# CakePHP v3 unable to use custom route class more than once

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to use custom route class. Everything is fine while i use only one route, but **Fatal error** otherwice

```
Cannot redeclare class Cake\Routing\Route\EventRoute in src/Routing/Route/EventRoute.php on line 24
```

In my **routes.php**

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    $routes->setRouteClass('EventRoute');
    $routes->connect('/:event', ['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'view']);
    $routes->connect('/:event/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Events']);
    $routes->connect('/:event/:number-:name', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view'], ['number' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['number', 'name']]);

    $routes->setRouteClass('InflectedRoute');
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Members', 'action' => 'login']);
}
```

In  that way i want to have short URLs for all my events in DB by it's slug and convert slug into param like

```
http://example.com/first_event -> Events.view ['event' => 'first_event']
http://example.com/coolest_event/edit -> Events.edit
http://example.com/past_event/12-someuser -> Users.view
```

and keep default Cake controller/action routing if no such event found.

File **EventRoute.php**

```
<?php

namespace Cake\Routing\Route;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class EventRoute extends Route
{
    public function parse($url, $method = '')
    {
        $params = parent::parse($url, $method);
        if (!$params) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!empty($params['event'])) {
            $events = TableRegistry::get('Events')->findBySlug($params['event'])->first();
            if (empty($events)) return false;
        }

        return $params;
    }    

}
```

System work as expected if i use only one (any of three routes above) but i can't use all three together.

It seems that CakePHP trying to include my **EventRoute.php** instead of include_once?
Or I'm doing somethig wrong?

Comment: Please show the contents of the `EventRoute.php` file.

Comment: @ndm added. It simple and straightforward, i copied it from Cake's example

Comment: You've copied too much, you're declaring the class in the `Cake\Routing\Route` CakePHP core namespace, the autoloader will find and load the file, but it won't find the class, and hence it will try to load the file again. It should be in the `App\Routing\Route` namespace.

Comment: @ndm yes, thank you. CakePHP Book said it should be the **Route classes are expected to be found in the Routing\\Route namespace of your application or plugin** All night long coding issue :(